# Is there a minimum Intelligence score for the thief?

Tags: ability-scores, adnd-1e, thief

The Player's Handbook mentions that high Intelligence is very important for a thief, but Intelligence Table I does not list a minimum value for a thief, only for an assassin.

Is there a minimum value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no minimum Int value for a thief. The lack of other mechanics in AD&D1 leaves a lot that is later moved to proficiencies (and in 3.x, skills) to simple attribute checks, and so one could reasonably expect a 1E DM to call for lots of Int Rolls to do various theifly things, like case a joint, spot the watch, etc.

Despite all that, no minimum was ever *required* to be a Thief; the sole requirement was (and even in later editions, still is) Dex 9+, and *only* Dex.

Comment: Exactly -  the rules make you free to be a bad thief, or at least not a very subtle one.

Comment: Isn't there also something of an issue with Intelligence as a broad concept?  A lot of meanings of intelligence are actually dictated by the player rather than the character.  Intelligence as an attribute in the game is a more abstract concept and as a result doesn't apply particularly neatly to thieves.

Answer (score 16):

6 is the minimum for all classes except the fighter, which can have 3-5 as well. The Thief needs a 9 or better in dexterity & 6 or better in all other attributes, save for wisdom, which can be as low as 3.

Comment: Do you have a page number in the 1E Player's Handbook or DM Guide for reference?

Comment: This is in fact correct. AD&D *PHB* page 10, INTELLIGENCE TABLE I, the line for ability score 5 reads: "Here or lower the character can only be a fighter", meaning that any other class (including thief) has an INT 6 minimum requirement. There are similar notes in the other tables, making 6 the typical minimum in all scores to have any choice of class. This is echoed by the thief minimum scores in OSRIC, p. 22.